# How to restrict access to a single page in an AWS Amplify app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am aware of restricting access to whole branch which I can redirect to using a subdomain such as `branch.website.com`.

But I want to restrict access to only `website.com/subpage` while all the remaining pages on the `website.com` remain unrestricted.

How can this be done for a website hosted using AWS Amplify?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "restrict"? Who/what should be allowed to see that page?

Comment: @defaultUsernameN This is what I mean: set a username and password so one can access the page only if they have those details.

Comment: Have you had a look at these amplify docs ([link 1](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/authentication/), [link 2](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/set-up-auth/)) for setiing up authentification? Seems like a good place to start.